# css- unable to keep the text aligned next to the icon

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

[image]

I'm making an ionic2 app. The portion of the screen you see above is from one of my pages where I display an address and a mobile number.

I added an icon for theaddress but as you can see it when it goes to next line, it starts from the left most side when I'm expecting the text to stay something like this.

```
(icon) This is where I show address, and i'm trying 
       to keep it aligned
```

Can anyone tell me how to do that? My knowledge of CSS is very weak.

My code:

```
  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon> <span text-wrap>This is where I show address, and i'm trying to keep it aligned </span></ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-icon name="call"></ion-icon> 01162464176</ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvwOmQ)

Comment: use flex to get it

Comment: @Anna Bella I have updated the answer after checking the full width and small screen. Please check it and if there is an issue please do comment.ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using grid layout. Put the icon and the text in 2 columns inside a row and give the icon column width to auto then even if the icon size changes it will adjust automatically, you don't have to hard code the width

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-auto>
      <ion-icon name="pin"></ion-icon>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col>
      <span text-wrap>This is where I show address, and i'm trying to keep it aligned </span>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your Fix, you need to add 2 css fixes.

```
.ion-ios-pin{
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 3%;
}
.item-inner span {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 95%;
   float: right;
   white-space: normal;
}
```

***Tested on your Code***

Updated code for adding `white-space: normal;`

***UPDATED CODE AFTER BUG CHECKING***

```
.ion-ios-pin{
       vertical-align: top;
       width: 12px;
}
.item-inner span {
       display: inline-block;
       width: calc(100% - 15px);
       float: right;
       white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.You Add below css.

**One more thing is if it's possible then add custom class to this tag `<ion-label>` so rest of the tag css will remain as it is.**

```
.ios ion-label {
    display: flex;
}
```

And set right side margin to this class **ion-icon.ion-ios-pin.item-icon**

```
ion-icon.ion-ios-pin.item-icon {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But there is no ion-label in the code I provided? @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.

Comment: But using this class .ios ion-label you can add css if it's generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list and define the icon as the bullet.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
}

div { margin-left: 25px; }

li:before {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f19c';
  margin: 0 5px 0 -25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  <li text-wrap>This is where I show address, and i'm trying to keep it aligned </li>
</div>
```